# 'Argument of \Hy@babelnormalise has an extra }' and pdfTeX error (ext1)

Tags: latex, pdflatex, overleaf

I had this error on overleaf that block the compiler.
It seems that I have an error with a hyperlink in the LaTeX code.
I try to remove all changes between my older versions, but nothing changed.

It's like if the code doesn't change anything to the error anymore

```
Argument of \Hy@babelnormalise has an extra }.

 
‪output.lot, 6‬
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 ...nih.gov/?term=\relax }}{2}{table.caption.8}
                                                  %
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=\relax 
! Paragraph ended before \Hy@babelnormalise was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.6 ...nih.gov/?term=\relax }}{2}{table.caption.8}
                                                  %
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

pdfTeX error (ext1): \pdfendlink cannot be used in vertical mode.

 
‪main.tex, 6‬
\close@pdflink ...\Hy@VerboseLinkStop \pdfendlink 
                                                  
l.6 ...nih.gov/?term=\relax }}{2}{table.caption.8}
                                                  %
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error by temporarily removing all the `\usepackage` commands and recompiling the document. After doing this, the error no longer appeared. I add again the `\usepackage` and everything went well!